# Hashing passwords into database

Tags: php, laravel

I am storing data into my database using MD5 and salt togethser for the hashing as shown below.

**Controller**

```
var salt = '112091318*32#'

$user_details = array ('password' => md5(crypt($this->input->post('pass'),$this->salt));
```

This provides a hash like `cf0c249ed76753e679bd17804c4739299`

Now my question is, is there a way that i can decrypt the hash back to normal text since , i have the salt ? If so, how ?

NB: I am new to how salt & MD5 works together. Please assist

Comment: You can't. The point of hashing is that it is irreversible.

Comment: You might want to alternatively look into [How to use password_hash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30279321/how-to-use-password-hash)

Comment: Not even might, you should definitely alternatively look at the above.

Comment: @NigelRen, password_hash can be reversed ?

Comment: [Hashing](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/hashing) is not [encryption](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/encryption) the second is reversible the first is not.https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4948322/fundamental-difference-between-hashing-and-encryption-algorithms

Comment: You don't want passwords to be reversed.  Ever.